# Issue with OpenGL textures facing wrong direction

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, textures

I've got a test texture in a new game that I'm creating, and for some reason, when I implement it into the game, the texture is flipped horizontally, instead of vertically. Why does this happen?

Here's a photo of the app.

[image: img]

As you can see, the little guy is flipped horizontally, almost as if he is sleeping. He should be facing vertically. Why is this happening, and how do I prevent it? I'll post both classes involved.

Player class:

```
   import java.io.IOException;

import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.Texture;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.TextureLoader;
import org.newdawn.slick.util.ResourceLoader;

public class Player {

    public Texture playerTexture;

    // Positions & speed
    public float xPos = 20.0f; // This is initial
    public float yPos = 450.0f; // Same as above.

    private float velocity = 20;

    public float gravityForce = 6;
    public float jumpVelocity = 25;

    private static int moveSpeed = 30 / 2;

    public boolean isSupported = false; // Once again, initial value. 
    boolean canJump = true;

    // movement methods

    public Texture grabTexture() {
        try {
            playerTexture = TextureLoader.
                    getTexture("PNG", ResourceLoader
                    .getResourceAsStream
                    ("resources/test_char.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return playerTexture;
    }

    public void applyGravity() {

    }

    private void printPos(String moveMethod) {
        System.out.println(moveMethod + " X: " 
    + xPos + " Y: " + yPos);
    }

    public void moveRight() {
        xPos += moveSpeed;
        printPos("Moving right!");
    }

    public void moveLeft() {
        xPos -= moveSpeed;
        printPos("Moving left!");
    }

    public void jump() {
        if (!isSupported) {

        }
    }

    public void shoot() {
        // do shooty stuff here
    }

}
```

Main (Launcher) class:

```
import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;

public class Main {

    private void display() {
        try {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(1000, 550));
            Display.setTitle("Unnamed Platformer Game");
            Display.create();
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }

        // OpenGL

        while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
            initGL();
            player.applyGravity();
            Display.update();
            Display.sync(60); // sync to 60 fps

            if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_D)) {
                player.moveRight();
            } else if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_A)) {
                player.moveLeft();
            } else if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_SPACE)) {
                player.jump();
            }
        }

        Display.destroy();
    }

    private void initGL() {
        // initial OpenGL items for 2D rendering
        GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
        GL11.glLoadIdentity();
        GL11.glOrtho(0, 1000, 550, 0, 1, -1);


        // start rendering player image
        player.grabTexture().bind();
        GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);

        GL11.glVertex2f(player.xPos, player.yPos);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);

        GL11.glVertex2f(player.xPos + 100, player.yPos);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 0);

        GL11.glVertex2f(player.xPos + 100, player.yPos + 100);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 1);

        GL11.glVertex2f(player.xPos, player.yPos + 100);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        GL11.glEnd(); // stop rendering this image
    }

    Player player = new Player();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: Post `test_char.png`.  The little dude could be sideways on-disk for all we know.

Comment: Your `nearVal` and `farVal` parameters for `glOrtho` might be backwards.

Comment: @genpfault You can find him under resources https://github.com/hasherr/Platformer

Comment: @genpfault He is 40x40, btw

Comment: @DrewMcGowen I don't think so.

Comment: So it looks like either x and y are being swapped, or there's a rotation in there somewhere. You might also want to set your `GL_MODELVIEW` matrix to the identity matrix.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen Setting the matrix to GL_MODELVIEW didn't help. I think it's a rotation problem, but I'm really not sure what a lot of the parameters mean in GL11.

Comment: Well like I said, the `glOrtho` call is the only odd-looking one. Have you actually tried swapping the `1` and `-1`?

Comment: @DrewMcGowen Yes. But I just figured out why you think it looks strange. I did switch two of the parameters. Minor difference, character now floats, but texture still did not flip.

Answer (score 2):

```
GL11.glVertex2f(player.xPos, player.yPos);
GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
```

The issue is you're calling these functions out of order. Whenever you call `glVertex2f`, OpenGL will grab whatever attributes are currently set and use that for the vertex. In this case, you're setting up the texture coordinate *after* setting the vertex, so the coords are "delayed" by one vertex. If you swap every pair of these calls, it should work.

Also, your call to `glOrtho` has the top and bottom parameters swapped. The bottom value is what the y value is supposed to be at the bottom of the screen (in this case, 0). Likewise for the top value.

Comment: Very very close. You got the texture to flip, just not the right way. The texture is now vertical, but it is upside down.

Comment: Almost everything you said worked, but the texture still didn't flip. These are significant changes to the code that only a beginner like me could make, but the texture still isn't fixed.

Comment: If swapping the top/bottom parameters doesn't flip the texture, I'm not sure what the issue is (perhaps the texture class is loading it upside-down).

Comment: No idea. Right now, I just solved the issue by repainting him upside down. Probably a bad idea, but I'll leave it for now.

Comment: @hasherr: Using the usual transformation setup, OpenGL places the texture image origin on the lower left. But most image file formats place the origin on the upper left. This combinations make it appear "upside down".

Comment: @datenwolf I see. Thanks for the input. Any way to fix this, besides just flipping the texture upside down in paint altogether?